# How to solve for an unknown in two different denominators?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

How to solve for an unknown in two different denominators?

In this equation:
$$F = \frac{GMm_3}{r_2} - \frac{Gmm_3}{d-r_2}.$$

Everything is given except for $r_2$.  How do I solve for $r_2$?  Is it possible?

Comment: @Justin:  Assuming this is a physics problem involving Newton's law of gravity, the units do not match.  If you calculate a force, you need a distance^2 in the denominator.

Comment: I neglected to mention that F = 0 in this scenario.  Will I still need to use the quadratic formula?

Comment: If you put $f=0$ in Arturo Magidin's answer, the quadratic term disappears, so not in that case.  And if the denominators are really $r_2^2$ and $(d-r_2)^2$ you will just have the ratio of squares with no linear term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, rewrite the right hand side as a single fraction by adding the fractions; factoring out $Gm_3$ simplifies matters a bit:
$$\begin{align*}
f &= \frac{GMm_3}{r_2} - \frac{Gmm_3}{d-r_2}\\
  &= Gm_3\left(\frac{M}{r_2} - \frac{m}{d-r_2}\right)\\
  &= Gm_3\left(\frac{M(d-r_2) - mr_2}{r_2(d-r_2)}\right).
\end{align*}$$
Then clear denominators by cross multiplying, and collect appropriate powers of $r_2$; you'll end up with a quadratic equation in $r_2$ that can be solved using the quadratic formula or other methods:
$$\begin{align*}
f & = Gm_3\left(\frac{Md - (M+m)r_2}{r_2(d-r_2)}\right)\\
fr_2(d-r_2) &= Gm_3\left(Md - (M+m)r_2\right)\\
fdr_2 - f(r_2)^2 &= Gm_3Md - Gm_3(M+m)r_2\\
0&= GMm_3d - \Bigl(Gm_3(M+m)+fd\Bigr)r_2 + f(r_2)^2.
\end{align*}$$

**Added.** If $f=0$, as you now write, then the equation becomes
$$0 = Gm_3\left(\frac {Md - (M+m)r_2}{r_2(d-r_2)}\right).$$
If $G\neq 0$ and $m_3\neq 0$, then this holds if and only if the numerator is $0$, if and only if
$$0 = Md - (M+m)r_2,$$
which is easy to solve.

If, as Ross suggests, the denominators should be squared and $f=0$, then you would instead get
$$0 = M(d-r_2)^2 - m{r_2}^2$$
which yields a quadratic equation in $r_2$ again, namely
$$(M-m){r_2}^2 - 2Mdr_2 + Md^2 = 0.$$

Comment: Or (in the denominator squared case) you can write $M(d-r_2)^2=mr_2^2$, take square roots (masses are positive), and have a linear equation.

Comment: @Ross: You have to note that you need to have  either $r_2,d-r_2\gt 0$ or $r_2,d-r_1\lt 0$ in that case, so that the original equation holds, but I agree that once you notice that your simplification works.

Comment: true, I am hypnotized by the appearance of Newton's law as opposed to an arbitrary equation.  These conditions will then be satisified.

Answer (score 1):

Try multiplying each side by *both* denominators, i.e. both $r_2$ and $d-r_2$, so that there are no fractions left. Combine like terms - in other words, group the terms with $r_2^2$ in them, the terms with $r_2$ in them, and the terms with no $r_2$'s in them. Then, treating $r_2$ as a variable we are solving for, we can apply the [quadratic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Quadratic_formula).

Answer (score 1):

You can, but you will probably use the quadratic formula.

$$f = \frac{GMm_3}{r_2} - \frac{Gmm_3}{d-r_2}.$$

$$f \cdot (r_2)(d-r_2) = GMm_3 \cdot (d-r_2) - Gmm_3 \cdot r_2$$

$$ -f \cdot r_2^2  + (fd + GMm_3 + Gmm_3) \cdot r_2 - GMm_3 d = 0$$

And this is quadratic in $r_2$, so solve using the quadratic formula. Aha - just as I am ready to post, this tells me that Zev has posted a similar answer. Well, this is his, except Texed up.

Answer (score 1):

A brief plea for symmetry!

The problem probably came from a situation in which there are two distances, $r_1$ and $r_2$, whose sum is $d$.  It could make life easier to use $r_1$ instead of $d-r_2$.  We then need to specify additionally that $r_1+r_2=d$.

So instead of a single equation, we have a system of two equations.  But there is much more symmetry. Calculations often are more pleasant, and the calculation is more likely to reveal structural information.